# Change event from click to onload

Tags: jquery, events

I am using a plugin for modal window, which opens the a window on click.

What I need to happen is to open this window automatically whenever the page is loaded.

Here is a part of code that trigers the modal window:

```
//Click event on element
        return this.click(function(e){
            add_block_page();
            add_popup_box();
            add_styles();

            $('.modal_box').fadeIn();
        });
```

How can I changes this to open modal automatically on page load.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    add_block_page();
    add_popup_box();
    add_styles();

    $('.modal_box').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $("#yourElement").trigger("click");
})
```

or put the code wich opens popup in some function and call it on document.load